# How do I query changes in a mysql-table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql-table structure and use it as a kind of logging table (entries_log):

```
    customer_id  | parent_id     | child_id  | quarter | month
    xyz          |     21        |  3        |  20121  | 201201
    xyz          |     21        |  5        |  20121  | 201201
    xyz          |     21        |  5        |  20122  | 201204
    xyz          |     21        |  6        |  20122  | 201204    
    xyz          |     21        |  4        |  20123  | 201207 
    ...          |     ...       |  ....     |   ....  |   ...
```

I hope you get the idea of the table. Now I want to track down if there has been any upgoing changes of the child_id for each customer_id and parent for each quarter related to the previous quarter (there can be a gap in the quarter-row, so the following example is possible and has to be considered : 20121...20122....20124).

So in the example above I just want to have the following output:

```
     xyz          |     21        |  5        |  20121  | 201201
     xyz          |     21        |  6        |  20122  | 201204
```

I worked out this query:

```
SELECT e.customer_id, e.parent_id, e.child_id, e.month, e.quarter
 FROM (
    SELECT MAX(month) AS maxmonth, quarter, max(child_id) 
     FROM entries_log AS e 
     WHERE EXISTS ( 
        SELECT * 
         FROM entries_log AS f 
         WHERE (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entries_log AS g 
             WHERE g.quarter = f.quarter 
             AND g.month = f.month
         ) <= 2 
         AND e.quarter > quarter 
         AND e.child_id> child_id
     )
     GROUP BY quarter
 ) AS x 
 INNER JOIN entries_log AS e ON e.quarter = x.quarter AND e.month = x.maxmonth;
```

I read [this](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/) site, which helped me a lot, but I still can't find the right query.

I appreciate your help, thank you!

Comment: It can be done using [variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html). Frankly unless you post a hefty bonus, I'm not going to show you the code, because it's just too much work.

Comment: thank you for your answer, bohemian. But i can't spend money for this problem ;)

Comment: He probably didn't mean money, but a karma bounty. But you don't have enough karma to post such a bounty yet. Anyway, what a splendid opportunity for you to learn! :-D

Comment: oh, i'm sorry. i didn't know about the "bounty"-system ;D thank you for that :)

Comment: I am not sure about your question, as your example output shows 2 rows in one quarter and month, so it is not a change between different quarters/months, but within... Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, you are right. I edited that part. There should be just the line "  xyz          |     21        |  5        |  20121  | 201201"  of course , because i want to display the highest value (child_id).

Comment: Can you explain better what's your criteria? I read you said you want to track the upgoing changes but can your justify your desired result ?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but perhaps adding a "record_changed TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" field could solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As Bohemian said, this is possible with variables. [Explain Extended](http://explainextended.com/2009/03/12/analytic-functions-optimizing-lag-lead-first_value-last_value/) has a nice write up of how to implement lead/lag in MySQL. You'll need to add some extra logic to handle your exact requirements, but it should point you in the right direction.